# repetitive csv loads with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to import with

```
 pd.read_csv
```

a repetitive importation as at first time I import

```
node_t1 = pd.read_csv('5mins/nodes/N01')
node_t2 = pd.read_csv('10mins/nodes/N01')
node_t3 = pd.read_csv('15mins/nodes/N01')
...
```

can I write only one time "N01", about only in the first row and the automatic code insert in all the row.

I need to implement this code because at the second, third,... time I need change 'N01' to 'N02' and after ..., 'N11'

Comment: So use some loops: `for time in ['5mins', '10mins', '15mins']: for node in range(1, 12): ...`

Comment: that's suspicious, both have the same typo in the title...

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
for n in range(1, 12):
    for time in ('5mins', '10mins', '15mins'):
        print('{time}/nodes/{n:0>2}'.format(time=time, n=n))
```

then you can easily store them in a dictionary

```
from itertools import product
dct = {}
for idx, (n, time) in enumerate(product(range(1, 12), ('5mins', '10mins', '15mins')), 1):
    dct['node{:0>2}'.format(idx)]  = pd.read_csv('{time}/nodes/{n:0>2}'.format(time=time, n=n))
print(dct)
```

which will be something like this (except that the values are your `csv` files not strings):

```
{'node01': '5mins/nodes/01',
 'node02': '10mins/nodes/01',
 'node03': '15mins/nodes/01',
 'node04': '5mins/nodes/02',
 'node05': '10mins/nodes/02',
 ....
 'node31': '5mins/nodes/11',
 'node32': '10mins/nodes/11',
 'node33': '15mins/nodes/11'}
```